# How to store an object in an object of objects in JavaScript using LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am new at JS and before asking I searched about this question but still did not find an answer. In the LocalStorage I have only one key defined as follows:

```
key={
  -prob1: string
  -prob2: Object 
      -prob21:string 
      -prob22:string
}
```

How can I store in `key` a given object of the same structure as `prob2` let's call it `obj` , is it like this ?    `localStorage.setItem('key.prob2', obj);` is this legal?

any ideas?thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store Objects using `localStorage` - you can only store there strings.

What you can do is convert your object to string (using `JSON.stringify`) and then save it.

```
obj = {
  a: {
    b: 'c'
  }
}

localStorage.setItem('myobj', JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(localStorage.getItem('myobj'));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myobj')));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/or91wp56/

Comment: thank you for replying , but I want to store obj in one property in myobj and not in myobj itself

Comment: You can always read that obj, insert new object in one of the properties, and save it back to the localStorage

Comment: I thought it was easy, I've been trying since hours, nothing is solving it ,how do you do that?

Comment: never mind , I'm the one who did it not quiet correct.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All you'd be storing with `localStorage.setItem('key.prob2', obj)` is `[object Object]` since it can only store strings, which probably isn't what you are looking for. I usually use a small wrapper class around `localStorage` to auto-serialize/deserialize, something like:

```
class Storage {
   static set(key, value) {
      let serialized = value;
      if (typeof value !== 'string') {
         serialized = JSON.stringify(serialized);
      }
      localStorage.setItem(key, serialized);
   }
   static get(key) {
      try {
         return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      } catch (e) {
         return localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
   }
}

Storage.set('foo', { bar: 'baz' });
console.log(Storage.get('foo').bar);
```